Does Terraform supoprt AWS PrivateLink for DynamoDB?
Dynamo DB now support Interface Endpoint. How to configure it with Terraform?

AWS PrivateLink for DynamoDB


Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222544/how-to-configure-a-vpc-endpoint-to-access-dynamodb-with-terraform

@jarmod, thanks for the link. I think it is for Gateway endpoint as it is about routing. Interface endpoint does not require routing setup. For Interface VPC Endpoing (PrivateLink), with private DNS enabled, it auto-resolves to the IP addresses of the PrivateLink ENI within the private subnet, if I recall correctly. I may be wrong, so kindly suggest if so.

You're right, apologies. Are you thinking that setting up an Interface VPC endpoint for DynamoDB is different to any other AWS service that supports interface VPC endpoints? I'd expect TF to support this with its standard interface VPC endpoint config, but with you indicating dynamodb as the service identifier/id. See here for a TF config for a S3 interface VPC endpoint, for example.

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "dynamodb" {
  vpc_id            = local.vpc_id
  service_name      = "com.amazonaws.ap-southeast-2.dynamodb"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
 
  security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.allow_from_security_group.id
  ]
 
  private_dns_enabled = false
}


